# How to programmatically (C#) import from the Xls-XML(xls file Saved in XML Format) data in to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, excel

I am in need of loading the data from an Excel file into SQL Server database. The Excel file is created by downloading the data from a web application into a data set. Data is pulled from a table in a SQL Server database to generate the Excel. When I tried to upload this same Excel file into the same table it errors out.

```
 HResult=-2147467259 Message=Could not find installable ISAM.
 Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine ErrorCode=-2147467259
```

The file format and extension of 'Report.xls' don't match the file could not be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway ?

Here is the code to save the data into database

```
      private void SaveFileToDatabase(string filePath)
      {
          String fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
          String excelConnString = string.Empty;

          //Create connection string to Excel work book
          if (fileExtension == ".xls")
          {
              excelConnString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""", filePath);
              //String excelConnString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""", filePath);
          }
          else
          {
              excelConnString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0""", filePath);
          }

          //Connection to Excel work book 
          using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
          {
              //OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel 
              using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [working$]", excelConnection))
              {
                  excelConnection.Open();
                  using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                  {
                      using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connect))
                      {
                          DBUtilities.RunSQLCommand("truncate table dbo.[DatabaseTable]");

                          //Destination table in db
                          sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = " DatabaseTable ";
                          sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                      }
                  }
          }
      }
      }
```

Code to create the Excel file from the data in the table

```
    private void ExportDataToExcel(String sprocCommand, String workBookName)
    {
        try
        {
            string attachment = "attachment; filename=report.xls";

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = string.Empty;
            Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "private");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", attachment);
            //Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            EnableViewState = false;

            DataTable dt = DBUtilities.GetData();
            DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;

            dt = null;
            dt = dv.ToTable();

            Response.Write(SendExcelXMLFormat(dt, workBookName));

            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ////TOOD   
        }
    }

    private string SendExcelXMLFormat(DataTable dTable, string WorkSheetName)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<?mso-application progid=\"Excel.Sheet\"?> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" ");
        sb.AppendLine("xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" ");
        sb.AppendLine("xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" ");
        sb.AppendLine("xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" ");
        sb.AppendLine("xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Styles> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Style ss:ID=\"s41\" ss:Name=\"60% - Accent1\"> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Font ss:FontName=\"Calibri\" x:Family=\"Swiss\" ss:Size=\"11\" ss:Color=\"#FFFFFF\"/> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Interior ss:Color=\"#95B3D7\" ss:Pattern=\"Solid\"/> ");
        sb.AppendLine("</Style> ");
        sb.AppendLine("</Styles> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Worksheet ss:Name=\"" + WorkSheetName+"\"> ");
        sb.AppendLine("<Table>");

        // Header Row
        sb.AppendLine("<Row ss:AutoFitHeight=\"0\"> ");
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dTable.Columns)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<Cell ss:StyleID=\"s41\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">" + dc.ColumnName + "</Data></Cell> ");
        }
        sb.AppendLine("</Row> ");

        // Data Rows
        foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<Row ss:AutoFitHeight=\"0\"> ");
            for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">" + Server.HtmlEncode(row[i].ToString()) + "</Data></Cell> ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine("</Row> ");
        }

        sb.AppendLine("</Table> ");
        sb.AppendLine("</Worksheet> ");
        sb.AppendLine("</Workbook> ");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the data from Excel to SQL Server means refer this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/593181/Load-GridView-from-Excel

here i loaded the gridview from excel and also copy the contents of excel to SQL Server using SQLBulkCopy().
Note: you can also get individual row from gridview and insert into the database.

have a look at it may helps.